# Querying User table from Community Super User profile in Communities

Tags: soql, lightning, community, controller

I am trying to query the user table from a controller called by a lightning component in Communities.

`User usr = [SELECT Id, Name, Email, Phone FROM User
            WHERE Id IN (Select OwnerId From Account Where Id = :u.AccountId)
            LIMIT 1];`

Running this from a community user it returns 0 rows. My sharing settings on the user record are private but the controller is using the without sharing notation. If I my self run that query I get the expected result.

`return [SELECT Id, Name, Profile.Name, AccountId,
      Manager.Name, Manager.Email,ContactId
  FROM User
  WHERE Id =:UserInfo.getUserId()];`

This query works. Is there some weird sharing setting that I am missing?

Basically I just want to be able to query the user table from a community user and can't.

Comment: Sharing keyword does not work with customer community login license..can you confirm what is license type of community user

Comment: I have same doubt, cannot access the user object's field in soql for community user, even though proper permissions are maintained. Following is my query:                                                                                                               
 select id, Designation__c, lookupuserobj__r.Id from childobject where Id =:someId

Comment: Ayub do you have a link to the documentation that points this out? Its a PartnerCommunityLogin1ML license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now this is an issue with the Spring19 release.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000BMV9QAO